# ImageSwitcher animation like homescreen sliding animation

Tags: android, animation

Here is a simple app which switches between images by right/left sweets

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/s"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Definition in onCreate:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sw = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);

        sw.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                ImageView myView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                myView.setImageResource(R.drawable.s);
                myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        GestureManager.onTouch(v , event);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                myView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams
                        (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                return myView;
            }
        });
    }
```

**GestureManager**

```
    static boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());                                             
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                pointerList.clear();
                mPoints.clear();
                mPoints.add(new MyPoint(pointerId , event.getX() , event.getY()));
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { 
                for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    mPoints.add(new MyPoint(event.getPointerId(i) , event.getX(i) , event.getY(i)));
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                processGesture(v,true);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void processGesture(View v,boolean singleGes){
        if(pointerList.size()==1){
            String msg = detectSingleGesture(mPoints);
            int size_x=MainActivity.sw.getWidth();
            switch (msg) {
                case "left":
                    TranslateAnimation left_to_right_in = new TranslateAnimation( size_x,0 , 0, 0 );
                    left_to_right_in.setDuration(1000);
                    left_to_right_in.setZAdjustment(AnimationSet.ZORDER_TOP);

                    TranslateAnimation left_to_right_out = new TranslateAnimation( 0,-size_x, 0, 0 );
                    left_to_right_out.setDuration(1000);
                    left_to_right_out.setZAdjustment(AnimationSet.ZORDER_BOTTOM);


                    MainActivity.sw.setInAnimation(left_to_right_in);
                    MainActivity.sw.setOutAnimation(left_to_right_out);
                    index--;
                    break;
                case "right":
                    TranslateAnimation right_left_in = new TranslateAnimation( -size_x,0 , 0, 0 );
                    right_left_in.setDuration(1000);
                    right_left_in.setZAdjustment(AnimationSet.ZORDER_TOP);

                    TranslateAnimation right_left_in_out = new TranslateAnimation( 0,size_x, 0, 0 );
                    right_left_in_out.setDuration(1000);
                    right_left_in_out.setZAdjustment(AnimationSet.ZORDER_BOTTOM);

                    MainActivity.sw.setInAnimation(right_left_in);
                    MainActivity.sw.setOutAnimation(right_left_in_out);
                    index++;
                    break;
            }
            if(index>4) index=0;
            if(index<0) index=4;
//            MainActivity.sw.setImageResource(image_ids[index]);
            Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp[index]);
            MainActivity.sw.setImageDrawable(d);

        }
  }
```

This code works properly and by sweeping left or right the animation is run and image is converted to the new one

**Question:**

How can I modify this code so that new Image moves in according to the movement of the finger on the screen, exactly like android homescreen?

should I still use ImageSwitcher  or there are other Views which suit better on this application?

(I tried to apply animation in `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` but I'm not sure if it a good solution is.)

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try screen slides with a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

> ViewPagers have built-in swipe gestures to transition through pages,
>   and they display screen slide animations by default, so you don't need
>   to create any

Comment: It is not what exactly I want but so close. It would be so easy for me (because of the other parts of the app) to have only one ImageView and update its image but using ViewPager it would be a bit difficult.